# Why only ConcurrentHashMap has concurrency level (out of all concurrentXX classes)?

Tags: concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Why out of all concurrentXX classes only ConcurrentHashMap has concurrency level argument in its constructor? While ConcurrentSkipListMap, ConcurrentSkipListSet, ConcurrentLinkedDeque, ConcurrentLinkedQueue don't?

Comment: It is defunct as of JDK8 and has no meaning. The JDK5 implementation was a set of hash maps guarded by locks, so the argument determined how many of these segments to use. The rewrite removed this limitation.

Comment: @Ben Manes What do you mean by "It is defunct as of JDK8 and has no meaning" ? What is defunct, concurrency level argument usage in ConcurrentHashMap? Why is it defunct? It is very interesting, may I ask you - could you please explain what is defunct?

Comment: Because the implementation was rewritten to no longer use it internally. You can read the internal documenting on the algorithm in the source code for details.